# Ruby compilation error in Ubuntu 10

Tags: ruby, compiling, install-from-source

I've got a vps which runs solusVM. I'm now trying to install ruby 1.9.2 in it.

I'm following this [guide](http://basedotextend.com/2010/09/30/installing-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2-phusion-passenger-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/):

After I run this command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

I got this error :

```
root@makserver:/usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/4252kB of archives.
After this operation, 4096B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: Bad file descriptor
(Reading database ... 21594 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2 (using .../libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb) ...
open2: fork failed: Cannot allocate memory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 12
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody tell me how I can correct this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are typos in the guide you linked to.

Initial steps should be:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
sudo apt-get install git-core
sudo apt-get install curl wget
```

I've also removed the `-y` flag, and prefixed the commands with sudo so you can (and probably should) run these with your regular (non-root) user.

I don't see the command you mention, `apt-get -f install`, anywhere on that page.   Having to use that generally means something is already broken.   You should probably start again from the beginning, making sure each step completes.

**However, I don't think you need to do any of this.**

Ubuntu's ruby1.9.1 package actually provides Ruby 1.9.2 .

If you look at the details in the output of `apt-cache show ruby1.9.1, you will find that the version provided in Ubuntu is actually **1.9.2**.

It is listed as 1.9.1, because the Debian maintainer is meaning to describe the binary compatibility version (1.9.1), instead of the Ruby software version (1.9.2) .

See this [Debian bug list entry](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=601526) for more information.

Here are a few snippets of the `apt-cache show ruby1.9.1` output :

```
Package: ruby1.9.1
Version: 1.9.2.0-1
Filename: pool/universe/r/ruby1.9.1/ruby1.9.1_1.9.2.0-1_i386.deb
[...]
Description: Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby 1.9.2
 Ruby is the interpreted scripting language for quick and easy
 object-oriented programming. [...]
 This package provides version 1.9.2 series of Ruby, which is binary-compatible
 with the 1.9.1 branch.
```